# Is Mifare Classic EV1 considered crackable nowadays?

Tags: mifare

I'm trying to find out whether **Mifare Classic EV1** cards are considered secure today or not. Given that existing articles are mostly about **Mifare Desfire EV1** cards and not the specific model I'm interested in, unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a direct answer through my searches. Despite Wikipedia mentioning that these cards are not suitable for security purposes according to NXP (the manufacturer), there isn't a credible source explaining the reason behind this statement. The [latest relevant article](http://cs.ru.nl/%7Erverdult/Ciphertext-only_Cryptanalysis_on_Hardened_Mifare_Classic_Cards-CCS_2015.pdf) claims that, with possession of one key from the card, it's possible to obtain other keys. But what about the settings with no default key? Are these settings also vulnerable?

The same article claims that based on research from an older paper, by capturing the communication between the card and the card reader for either a successful or unsuccessful authentication attempt, there's a possibility of cracking a card key. However, it appears that the referenced article in this context is specifically applicable to regular Mifare Classic cards and may not accurately reflect the situation for the EV1 version.

So, in short, is **Mifare Classic EV1** considered hackable when all the keys are changed? If so, is there any public papaer/tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to the first part, according to the [manufacturer](https://www.mifare.net/en/products/chip-card-ics/mifare-classic/security-statement-on-crypto1-implementations/), changing all the keys is "partially effective":

> NXP believes the counter-measures present in products using Crypto1
> can only be partially effective if all keys in a card are diversified.
> The costs involved to change existing systems to fully diversified
> keys will likely mean that this countermeasure will not be extensively
> deployed.